# How to convert BGRA to RGBA in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, urhosharp

I am using AVFoundation to get real-time frames from camera and display to the UrhoSharp.

However, seems the Texture2D in UrhoSharp is not support the BGRA from AVVideoOutput. So I want to convert the "CVPixelBuffer" to RGB format.

I found there is an API in vImage "vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888", which can convert the BGRA to ARGB but this is not provided by Xamarin.

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin, but the general idea is to create a bitmap context of the desired format and then draw the image in that context. See [Technical Q&A 1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1509/_index.html). That's drawing via CoreGraphics, but you can also use the UIKit drawing methods, too.

Comment: Is that using GPU to renderer the image?

Comment: I would guess not, but I don’t know. It depends upon what UIKit and/or CoreGraphics does internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Accelerate.framework` consists of `C` functions, so:

```
vImage_Error vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(    const vImage_Buffer *src,
                                                const vImage_Buffer *dest,
                                                const uint8_t       permuteMap[4],
                                                vImage_Flags        flags )     VIMAGE_NON_NULL(1,2,3)  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING( __MAC_10_4, __IPHONE_5_0 );
```

Can be used via:

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage")]
public unsafe static extern vImageError vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(ref vImageBuffer src, ref vImageBuffer dest, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]uint[] permuteMap, vImageFlags flags);
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533241-vimagepermutechannels_argb8888

Ref: `Conversion.h`

- `/Applications/Xcode9.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Headers`

Comment: Btw, the `vImage_Error` should be the `vImageError`. Thank you!

Comment: @Developer Your right if you are `using Accelerate;`, I have an Xamarin.iOS independant library wrapping Accelerate.framework, so I use `using vImage_Error = System.nint;` 

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, I am trying to do the same just for vImageConvert_ARGB8888To420Yp8_CbCr8 instead. I would really appreciate if you can help me here. Especially the info parameter is the one I am struggling with. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533164-vimageconvert_argb8888to420yp8_c?language=objc - Also it could be nice, if you have the time to show how the method is actually called. :)

Comment: @dynamokaj You should ask a new question with what you have done so far

Comment: @SushiHangover I have done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327771/how-to-convert-argb8888-to-420yp8-cbcr8-in-xamarin-ios I really appreciate if you can have a look at it, I am willing to pay you also. :)